# Designing state for Reusable React Components and Browser history

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for ways to structure state in my React components so that I can accomplish two goals together: (1) managing browser history in a complex app, and (2) letting individual components be easily reusable in environments outside the main app.

The app has a Panel component which lets users navigate and read content on our site. In the main app, multiple panels can be opened and arranged together. Outside of the main app, there are other pages where I'd just like to be able to easily drop in a single Panel component.

As this code has developed so far, each Panel has a rich state representing what content it has loaded and other display settings. This makes it easy to drop in to another page - I can just render a Panel component and the user can interact with it and it takes care of itself.

For browser history however, this is getting hairy. There is an App component which manages multiple Panels and the states pushed to and popped from history. In order for it to have a complete picture of the state of the whole app, each panel pushes up a copy of its state when changes occur. When state is popped from the history that App component can pass down an initialState from each of the Panels it renders. As you can imagine, this is getting messy and error prone with the cycles of updates that end up looping back to each other.

It feels like the approach I need to take is to Centralize State (a la the recommendation [here](http://aeflash.com/2015-02/react-tips-and-best-practices.html)) and try to make each individual Panel stateless. Since it will be a significant effort to rewrite all the calls to `setState` already in the code, I'm trying to evaluate if this is the only way to go. It also feels like this approach will make it harder to reuse the components outside the app. I'll lose the feeling that a Panel is a self-contained component which I can just render on a page, since it will need some kind of outside manager as well to handle its state and all the events that change it from within.

What would you recommend?

Comment: This will likely get closed due to asking for recommendations rather than having an issue, but it strikes me that the next step for you is [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or a framework based on Flux, such as [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux).

Comment: In regards to browser history have you looked into a library such a [React-Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)?

Comment: I agree with both previous comments, but can you elaborate on the history that you're storing? Is it just a panel open/close history, or is the "rich data" being serialized into a url or something else entirely?

Comment: Basically the full state of the application is being serialized into the URL. This includes what panels are open and what state they are in. Each panel can have specific content loaded, and can also be in navigational states as the user browses content in the panel. In the App component there is a function `shouldHistoryUpdate` which is called via `componentDidUpdate`. It examines the state changes a determines if they warrant being pushed to the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

I made a application on react and implementing react-router you can pass throw the URL data to every panel know in what state are and what content is loaded, by example you can have an url like:
http://yoururl.com/index/user/userID1/item/itemID2/filterDate?="19/09/2014"

To reuse your panels you can made a url that made an herarchical route view: You can pass throw components everything you want to know on the render wich view you have to load.

My routerDomExample

I recommend to investigate react-router.